# Traveling inside Schengen without a ticket to fly back home (Venezuela)

Tags: schengen, venezuelan-citizens

I'm Venezuelan, currently in Finland as a tourist but I'm applying for a residence permit. I entered Schengen 80 days ago, now I need to fly to Spain just for 3 days to do some paperwork.

Can I come back if I show I have a residence permit being processed in Finland and I have a few days of the 180/90 left? I'm asking this because Finnair gave me a tough time when I was doing the check-in for Madrid-Helsinki two months ago, of course I didn't had the residence permit on hold like now, I was just coming here as a tourist but they demanded me a ticket to go back to Venezuela (not even outside of Schengen, especially to my home country). So I would like to know which are my rights and if it's advisable for me to travel inside Schengen on the last days of my visa free time, even though that Finnish migration assures that I can wait for the decision here.